# Where does the "1-10" attractiveness scale come from?

Tags: etymology, american-english

When did the "1-10" attractiveness or beauty scale become part of our vocabulary?
I've seen quite a few papers and books using a 1-10 attractiveness scale around the 1970s for several purposes and terms like "she's a ten" or "beauty scale" skyrocketed beginning from the 80s and 90s but is there a film or a book that truly popularized the concept?
I found the movie [*10* by Blake Edwards](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_(film)) and the Ozone's song "she's a ten" as early examples of medium using terms related to the attractiveness scale.

Comment: Hmm... if someone says "she's a 10" I think they are referring to her clothing size.

Comment: @WeatherVane Are you serious?

Comment: @HotLicks I thought we had more respect in the 21st century, perhaps not. The whole idea demeans the "ones".

Comment: The usage has been around since I was a kid (which is before the 70s).

Comment: A BRIEF CULTURAL HISTORY OF THE 1–10 SCALE FOR FEMALE HOTNESS. https://melmagazine.com/en-us/story/female-hotness-1-10-rating-scale-history#:~:text=Indian%20mathematicians%20invent%20the%20first,the%20numbers%200%20through%209.

Comment: Likert devised the first 'Likert scale' in 1932; these and  'Likert-type scales' (these latter used for other than measuring opinions/attitudes) usually run from 1 to 5 (rather than 10), discretely.. The 1-10(+) Richter scale for earthquake magnitudes dates from 1935; it is measurable rather than subjective.

Comment: Yes, I thought 1 to 10 was just the most popular/convenient Likert-type scale (e.g. for self-assessing pain in the hospital).

Comment: US soldiers in Vietnam quickly learned that this scale was reversed over there. "Number One" was the best, and "Number 10" was the worst.

Comment: Is this usage specific to the English language?

Comment: On our sister-site, ELL: [What does “She’s a ten and I am a 5” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309962/what-does-she-s-a-ten-and-i-am-a-5-mean) and [What does "Your old man's a ten" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127655/)

Comment: I suppose, but it needs to be checked, before the 1970s highly-attractive women were called  "bombshells", "smoking hot", "Venus" or a "pin-up"

Comment: There may be two distinct questions here. One is how speaking of attractiveness in terms of such a scale became widespread. The other is how the use of the scale came to be expressed by locutions such as 'she **is** a ten', rather than, say, 'she scored ten points on the 1-10 scale'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“A perfect 10” was popularized by the romantic comedy film “10,” starring Bo Derek, whose character is considered the perfect woman by the man who courts her. It was released in October 1979. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo_Derek

But a “perfect 10” was already in use in various sports,especially gymnastics. Ten-pin bowling was also established in the United States in the early 20th century; a strike is a perfect 10.

Comment: In gymnastics, etc. such scales are explicitly, formally established. It is possible that their use in these formal evaluations led some people to express their informal evaluations of attractiveness in terms of the 1-10 scale, but I think that the OP would like to know more about when and how that shift in usage occurred. The film may have, as you say, popularised this way of talking, but did its creators come up with that terminology on their own, or were they building upon something that already existed in everyday communication?